# Potentially false result of derivatives in MatLab

Tags: matlab, newtons-method

```
clear; clc; close all;

f = @(x) sin(x) + cos(x);
df = @(x) (f(x+0.0001)-f(x))/0.0001;

tol = 1e-6;
iter = 0;
x_0 = 1;
while iter < 1000
    x_1 = x_0 - f(x_0)/df(x_0);
    if abs(f(x_1)) < tol
        break
    end
    x_0 = x_1;
    iter = iter + 1;
end
disp([x_1, f(x_1), iter])
```

The code block above shows calculates the root of an equation using the Newton-Raphson method. However, it reaches the result in only the 2nd iteration and the derivative equation given by my instructor which is supposed to give the derivative gives a different result than I expected. How can I ensure that the derivative is correct and the while loop gives the correct result in the end?

I tried to put the derivative manually but it gives a different result.

Comment: The answer your code provides is correct. What is the expected result? Try changing the initial guess to find another root of the equation.

Comment: If you set `tol = 1e-12`, it'll do 3 iterations instead of 2. There is nothing wrong with your code. Your initial value is not close to a zero, and so the zero this finds is not the nearest one (2.356) but the next one over (5.498). Still, the method does just the right thing and finds a zero quite efficiently. Why do you think this is wrong? You seem to worry about it taking only 2 iterations? You can easily verify that `f(x_1)` is very close to zero, so the `x_1` value found is a zero. Your other concern is about the derivative being incorrect, maybe you manual derivative is wrong?

Comment: You can use `df = @(x) cos(x) - sin(x);`, and you get the same outputs (or close enough). You can plot `f(x)` and `df(x)` and see that they are as expected: `x=linspace(0,7,10000); plot(x,f(x)); hold on; plot(x,df(x));`.

Comment: Nasılsınız Tutku, would you please be so kind to show the code of your instructor so readers can compare?

Comment: Hello again Tutku, when you say 'calculate the root' which one? within [0 pi] the function has 2 zeros not one. Isn't your code supposed to find ALL zeros within assumed interval? or is it ok just finding 1st zero upwards?

Comment: also, Tuztu, are you aware you are using the SECANT METHOD, not the Newton-Raphson method?